# Why upload an app to app store?

Tags: ios, ipa

I can make a package (xxx.ipa) for an app, then synchronize this package to IOS device. Someone can do this and why need upload app to app store?

Answer (score 3):

When you sign an application yourself, you can only install to iOS devices that you registered on provisioning center (up to 100 devices with the developer program - 100$).

In other words, if you wanted reach 1M million users with your app, it would cost you $1M. So you **NEED** the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

We need to the upload an App to AppStore in to access it universally with no limitation of the number of user who can use it . Creating an Adhoc (.ipa) for any app and sync it to the device has certain limitation as you cannot distribute your .ipa to more than 100 devices , also it has validity 1 year by which only you can use the app . There are many more reasons to be explained for it . Go through the Apple Guideline in order to get more information . Hope it help you!

Answer (score 0):

- It takes away all the manual labour. Installing an app from App Store is easier than manually via iTunes. Updating is even more easier.
- You don't have to know all unique device identifiers up-front.
- You won't break Apple rules (it forbids distribution without App Store for anything other than testing or internally in one organization)